# using character entities in java properties file

Tags: java, properties, character-encoding

I'm trying to add some text to a web app via a java .properties file. I want the text to have an en-dash in it. If I add the character entity, thus:

```
myProp=Foo &ndash; Bar
```

or

```
myProp=Foo &#8211; Bar
```

I get the code in my output. If I add the literal character to the properties file (and save as UTF-8):

```
mProp=Foo – Bar
```

I get the literal character in the output. How do I add the character entity to the output??

Answer (score 2):

The `load(InputStream)` method of the `Properties` class always decodes text files as ISO-8859-1. It doesn't "know" what encoding the editor used when it saved the file.

You can create your own `Reader` with the correct character encoding, and use the [`load(Reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) method instead.

Or, you can stick with ISO-8859-1 and escape characters from other character sets using Unicode escapes (`\uXXXX`, for example, "\u8211" instead of "–").

Comment: This doesn't explain how he gets the literal character in the output for the literal dash.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a HTML entity and the second one is a XML entity. So to get the first one displayed as a dash, it should be displayed unescaped by a HTML file and to get the second one displayed as a dash, it should be displayed unescaped by a XML file. Also, the files should be displayed using a proper tool, which can in this case be a webbrowser.

Are you displaying it unescaped in a HTML/XML file using a proper tool?

To determine whether it's escaped or unescaped, rightclick the page in webbrowser, choose *View Source* and you should check if the first ampersand is **not** being escaped as `&amp;` which would end up like `&amp;ndash;` or `&amp;#8211;` respectively. How to avoid escaping depends on the view technology you're using to display it. If it's for example JSP/JSTL `<c:out>`, then you should set the `escapeXml="false"` attribute.